# plotly::plot_geo fitting parent div in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, bslib

I am struggling to create a map in plotly that fully fits the height and width of a card in Shiny. See a minimum reproducible example below and a screenshot of what I would like to achieve. Any advice on how to proceed would be much appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  card(plotlyOutput("plot", width = "100%", height = "100%"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_geo(type = 'scattermapbox') %>% 
      layout(
        showlegend = FALSE,
        paper_bgcolor="#F0F9FE",
        geo = list(scope = 'world'))
})
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: Screenshot displaying in blue the card that I would like to fully fit with the map]

Comment: Please check [this](https://plotly.com/r/setting-graph-size/). However, there does not seem to be a proper way to [modify the aspect ratio of the map](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-can-the-resolution-of-a-scattergeo-plotly-figure-in-python-be-increased/1192/3?u=ismirsehregal).

Comment: `card` requires Bootstrap 5. Replace `fluidPage` with `page_fluid`.